# How to extend django's default User in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, django-models, pymongo, mongoengine, djongo

I'm using mongodb as database and trying to extend the django's inbuilt user model.
here's the error I'm getting:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Field "auth.User.id" of model container:"<class \'django.contrib.auth.models.User\'>" cannot be of type "<class \'django.db.models.fields.AutoField\'>"']
```

Here's my `models.py`:

```
from djongo import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=User)
    mobile = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pincode = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Comment: at first, the `profile` should inherit from `from mongoengine.document import Document` if you want to use MongoDB as your DB, but I'm not sure you can define user as an embedded field from django modes.

Comment: @MaryamAbdoli, `Profile` shouldn't inherit from `from mongoengine.document import Document`. Here it inherits from `djongo.Model` and djongo is supposed to take care about everything.

Comment: Also using `EmbeddedField` is not a good idea, because it will duplicate user data in the db. Just keep the user id in the model and query separately.

Comment: @suraj Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @ShivamYadav yes

Comment: @Suraj Can you share the resource please?

Comment: Whats is the solution found, @Suraj ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `EmbeddedField` is not a good idea, because it will duplicate user data in the database. You will have some user in the Users collection and the same data will be embedded in the `Profile` collection elements.

Just keep the user id in the model and query separately:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField() #or models.TextField()
    mobile = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pincode = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

### It is simple as defined in the documentation.

So, first, use djongo models as the `model_container`, and I suppose the User model is the Django model, not the djongo model.

And the second thing, make your `model_cotainer` model abstract by defining in the Meta class as given below.

```py
from djongo import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Blog
    )    
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Ref: https://www.djongomapper.com/get-started/#embeddedfield